# Cons of using Internet Explorer's Compatibility Mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode

**What are cons of force a web site viewed in IE to compatible mode? Say we force IE9 to [IE8 compatiblity mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx)?**

- Performance drawbacks
- Can't use any new IE9 specific features like HTML5/CSS3/SVG

---

#### Why?

We run legacy web app which is developed since 2000 so it's a mess ball fighting to be compatible with Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE6/7/8 and now we decide to add IE9 to the list. But with IE9 we run in issues with printing, "Permission deniend" JavaScript errors (probably something about cross-frame JavaScript calls) and next issues - the easy workaround is to force IE9 to behave as a IE8 and then everything works fine. But I am still not sure if it's way to go...

Comment: Your errors most likely stem from using code that specifically targets IE, which is a prime example of why feature detection is superior to browser detection.  Also, forcing IE 9 into compatibility mode definitely isn't the way to go - IE 10 is just around the corner so ideally you want to be taking advantage of the better performance and improved features from IE 9 and 10.

Comment: Why I should bother about IE10? In our case we don't care about new features, we only care about same user experience for all. Yes we can fix all bugs but it will cost more money than this fix, so I need to know - are there any cons which in the end cause that it will cost more than fix IE9 compatibility?

Comment: The improved features include not supporting getElementsByTagName. That alone is worth upgrading...</sarcasm>

Comment: It might be worth investing your time and money on solution-specific fixes based a framework like YUI, or possibly jquery, where browser abnormalities can be normalised. When testing for IE9, we ended up spending.. 3 hours upgrading to the latest YUI release... and all of our woes were solved for free.

Answer (score 2):

> first our app is public site (for our clients)

You have a public website developed in 2000 and it doesn't work on modern browsers? Deprecate it or re-write it.

Don't hack your code to support modern browsers, the website is clearly poorly written and doesn't apply to standards. **You can't get away with this.**

The only place where you can get away with this level of incompatibility is intranet applications and even then you should simply state **"it works on browser X, live with it"**

**You can't say that to public facing clients.** I mean you can try, but have fun losing business to your competitors.

**Re-develop your website to match the W3C HTML/CSS standards and the ES5 standards** and it will be completely future facing (for some years).

Alas, the way the web works is that anything more then **5 years old is deprecated.** So either re-write it every 5 years or get out of the web business.

In terms of actually using compatibility mode, don't. IE6-8 are horrible engines and should be avoided like the plague. If you use them then you can't write future facing standards compliant code.

Your code needs to **match the standards** and you should fix / shim / patch any browser specific bugs where those browsers **don't implement the standards**.

Comment: I read it as being an extranet. In which case the clients probably define the browsers it must run under, and they are often less forward thinking than nomal people. Meaning IE6 is still what some places insist on using. And stating the browsers it runs on is far more acceptable than a proper public site.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat he mentioned it's a public site, if it's an extranet or intranet website running on a limited network then it's acceptable to state "we support these browsers". If it's public then you need to support Current/Previous browsers of the big 5.

Comment: I think we have read the same thing in different ways. I read the quote at the top of your post as meaning extranet-type of app. You read it as fully public web site. In the latter case, you are correct - it MUST support the latest browsers in full mode, pretty much as soon as they come out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say you have tested in IE6/7/8/9 until you have tested in those different versions. Emulating the test environment is not the same as using the test environment. To my knowledge IE7/8 compatibility modes are the older render engines, not the underlying browser as a whole, bugs and all. It is closed source so you will never know.

Convert Microsoft's free to download virtual disk images for cross-browser testing to Virtualbox images and put them on a machine that just runs Virtualbox. An old machine will do, run the VMs headless and access them with remote desktop. In that way you will be able to test in all browsers without burdening your machine with MS/Spyware.

Comment: +1 for your username, and +1 if I could for pointing out that emulated IE compats are *not* IEs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your system admins can set IE to compatibility mode for all intranet traffic using the Group Policy Editor.  Any site you create will from this point forward, you can add a meta tag to force IE9 to render natively and use all the newer features...

I'm having to do that on my current project using the following doctype and meta tag in my header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but... first our app is public site (for our clients) and how is this related to question "What are cons of force a web site viewed in IE to compatible mode? Say we force IE9 to IE8 compatiblity mode?" ? see my comments on my initial question

Comment: In the case of an external app, then could you just not switch the meta tag on the old app to force compatibility with IE 8?  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" />`

Comment: Alternatively <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" /> - this will choose Chrome Frame if present, or the latest version of IE if not.

Answer (score 1):

Compatability mode is something that MS introduced to give people some chance to upgrade their applications, not for long term use. AFAIU.

If you want your application to be compatible with IE9, then you will have to change it. If you are trying to maintain IE6-9 compatibility then you have a real challenge, and you should consider whether this is really practical - in essence, you need at least 2 distinct sets of html. Is this practical for you?

IE9 compatibility mode is different form IE9 and IE8 - it draws bits from both. So you need to do a full test agaisnt the compatibility mode version, and ensure that it remains working against this.

So in answer to the question, the cons are that you are not being IE9 compatible, and there is a danger that when IE10 comes out, your code will not run against that in any mode. You are putting the effort into compatibilty testing without providing for future changes. You would do better, in the longer term, to make your code IE9 compatible. Also, the message you are giving your clients is that your code base is not going to be compatible for much longer. Unless you are talking to them about a re-work, this is a real negative.

However, it sounds like your entire code needs a re-work, to forget about IE6 and be written for modern working browsers. Using compatibility mode until that happens is probably OK. If you do this - and tell your clients - then staying in compatibility mode is viable.

Comment: In fact, IE9 does not work like IE8 which doesn't work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE6 and none of them work like any of the other far more modern browsers. Throw in compatibility mode and it's just one huge mess.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat: sometimes, despite popular and sensible opinion, it just isn't feasible to drop support for IE6. Yes, even though Google have, and Microsoft will in the next couple of years.

Comment: @Danjah Sad but true. I think what I meant was that the code needs to be reworked for later browsers, and maybe legacy support for IE6. But trying to produce a single application across all versions of IE from 6 onwards is not practical. If IE6 and IE9 support is needed, you need to support two different product streams.

Comment: Aye, and I'd have to say that Michal's comments about the cost of update appear frail in the face of the task at hand... but in general as you say, product streaming would be a mid-range expense option in the (apparent) circumstances...

Comment: @Danjah he means forget IE6 and write to the standards, then patch any IE6 specific bugs you care about. The easiest way to support IE6 is to force it to run with JavaScript off. Supporting HTML/CSS that works in IE6 is quite easy. If users want the UI enhancements then they can use a _modern_ browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using compatibility mode will NOT cause the browser to use the JavaScript engine that was present in the old version of IE.

By that I mean it will run any JavaScript code using the IE9 engine. Which was a problem for us when debugging an old product that had a problem with IE7/8.

Comment: still it resolves "Permission denied" js error, so it at least change behaviour of some javascript interaction with DOM ... next odd thing which talks against your opinion is that when you ran pure javascript benchmark [SunSpider 0.9.1](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9.1/sunspider-0.9.1/driver.html) there is a small difference (in my case around 20%) in performence so there must be something about javascript in compatibility mode

Comment: I know this is old - but I do not think it is correct.  At least, not with IE11 specifically.  When I put IE11 in IE7 compatibility mode I will see javascript errors whenever any code tries to use a function like .trim(), or .hasOwnProperty() as these were not supported in IE7.  

I fixed the issue within our application by changing to the jQuery version of these functions, but still, it suggests to me that compatibility mode DOES change the JavaScript engine

Comment: When I got home after posting this it occurred to me that the scenario I described was NOT from compatibility settings, it was using the developer panel in IE11 with browser emulation mode set to IE7.  In that case, I would not be surprised if the browser itself WAS using at least some of the older functionalities from that version - as opposed to compatibility mode which would only affect the Browser (rendering) mode.  

Having said that, I do believe that the rendering engine difference can potentially impact JavaScript, to a degree, if that rendering somehow changes the DOM?