# Cons of using IE compatibility mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cons of using Internet Explorer's Compatibility Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125040/cons-of-using-internet-explorers-compatibility-mode)

I was going through my site in IE before uploading it to the host like I always do, but I noticed some strange stuff like, exactly sam items(submit buttons in partial view) somewhere shown, somewehere not.. I know most of the tricks in IE, but I never seen something like this, but when I put Compatibility mode in IE 8 settings everything is working correctly, I'm using HTML5. So I want to trigger it from code, would this declaration put IE in comatibility mode?

```
<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=7; IE=8” />
```

If so, are there any cons of using this command?

Comment: @Nathan that question is about javascript issues, I am wondering about css issues.

Comment: Are you sure your content is using correct CSS? Html5/CSS3 to render in IE7/8? Neither of the version is know to support Html5 better than IE9... Forcing non-compat mode makes a lot of sense, but forcing IE7/8 for content that is HTML5 sounds plain wrong.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Well my code should work even on ie7, im using html5 shiv and css PIE for CSS3

Comment: Maybe you should have started from asking this question. Still makes no sense to me forcing usage of older rendering engine when later is available and should be able to render content as is. I.e. even IE10 would have to render your site in IE8 mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes versions higher than 7 (or 8) such as IE9 (or 8) to render as an older version.  The con of this is you lose out of functionality that the newer version provides and thus reducing the the potential quality of experience of the visitor.

Typically you would use the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag when you don't have time to get your existing site to render properly on the more-web-friendly versions of IE.

Comment: I'm currently testing on IE8, and the description of meta X-UA-Compatible says it will use the highest declared mode, and that is in my case IE8? Or am I wrong?

Comment: With your declaration, IE8 and up will render as IE8, IE7 will render as IE7.

Comment: Thanks for clarification,this answers my question,but I guess it will then stay a mystery why does my stuff render correctly in Comapatibility mode.

Comment: Your website probably renders correctly because IE7 and IE8 have rendering quirks which were accounted for when programming the site originally.  These quirks are probably not apparent in IE9 rendering natively.

Answer (score 1):

The cons I know including:

1. You lose newer IE JavaScript features. For example, if you set it back to anything lower than IE8 you will lose native JSON, because it was introduced by IE8. Then you have to include json2.js (or alike) in your page in order to use JSON.
2. It's not totally the same as an old IE. IE9 with IE8 compatibility mode isn't exactly the same as a real IE8. There are small differences. Keep improving your pages and one day you will find you make something displays differently in IE8 compatibility mode and a real IE8.

Unless you just need a quick fix and you don't need to modify this page in the future, try to avoid using on compatibility mode.

Comment: I also included json2 already to support SignalR on IE7, but given the answers I will rather create another css to work conditionally on IE then use Compatibility mode. It really seems worth the trouble to fix it the right way!